# Syntax issue with sending email via mutt on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, mutt

I'm trying to send an email from my Amazon EC2 node using mutt and I'm getting an error that I'm assuming is syntax but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to send an email with a txt attachment

```
echo "Sending Test" | mutt -a test.txt -s "test email" name@emaildomain.com
```

However I get the following errors:

```
Can't stat name@emaildomain.com: No such file or directory
name@emaildomain.com: unable to attach file
```

It is clearly trying to attach a file that is the name of the email but I don't understand why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In recent versions of mutt the `-a` option is designed to allow multiple arguments so that you can do `-a *.txt` to attach any number of files which match that pattern. Because of this it must be the last option used and separated from the recipients by `--`:

```
echo Sending Test | mutt -s "test email" -a test.txt -- name@example.com
```